# Midi set tempo meta event

Tags: midi

The Set Tempo Meta event itself contains a delta field as well. Is this delta defined in the previous tempo or in the new tempo (the tempo in this event)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delta times are expressed in MIDI ticks, which are independent of tempo.

If you are calculating the real-time duration in microseconds of the delta time of the new tempo, you would use the MPQN of the previous tempo event to perform that calculation.